# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in infinityfree

Tags: php, mysqli

En esta mañana me aparecion este codigo error "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" en mi hosting de infinityfree y no encuentro la solución, primero revise si era el php y le hice unos cambios y dejo de aparecer el codigo de error 500 pero sigue sin cargar la página.

Comment: Buenas, David, ¿cuál es tu pregunta exactamente? Échale un ojo al [tour]. Y el idioma oficial del sitio es el español.

Comment: Bueno en esta parte ya lo termine solucionado porque me parecia este error porque se actualizo el php de host y me aparecia un error 500 que a la final cambio el nombre del hostname.

Comment: Ya solucione normalmente "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo falló: nombre o servicio desconocido" carga ciertas versiones del codigo mysqli esto significa que se actualizo php. ¿Por qué no conectas la base de datos en infinityfree? Es porque cambio el nombre de host, por ejemplo: sql1000.infinityfree.asx a sql1000.epizy.asx